# ODBC refuses to statically link to libcmt.lib under VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

There is a short response from Microsoft regarding this issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470376/odbc-application-linking-with-odbccp32-lib-gets-link-errors-in-vs2010-beta-1?wa=wsignin1.0#tabs

Basically, their response doesn't seem to address the problem.

Our application needs to statically link to the C libraries, but there is a linker error when attempting to do so.  Microsoft's answer seems to be "dynamically link instead", but that's not an option.  Their alternative is to "Use the version of odbccp32.lib that came with Vista SDK."  However, I am unaware as to how to force VisualStudio 2010 to use a different version of the ODBC library?

I just spent the last hour trying every conceivable search through the .vcxproj and .sln files for any references to odbccp32.lib.  None.  I similarly looked for ODBC.  None.  Looking at all of the compiler & linker options for the project(s) in question: nothing refers to ODBC whatsoever.  The only connection between our application and ODBC I can see is the #include <sql.h> and <sqlext.h>.  However, even those files do not refer to odbccp32.lib (or any other .lib or linker option).

The only references to odbccp32.lib I can find at all are in .obj files.  So it appears that VS2010 automagically knows which ODBC libraries to link against based on what functions are referenced in our software (SQLConnect(), for example).

So how might I:

1) "obtain Vista SDK version of odbccp32.lib"?

2) cause VS2010 to link against that version?

-OR-

Is there a better way to solve this?!  Right now I am unable to proceed with a conversion of our software from VS2008 -> 2010 unless I can find a way to force this goofy software to compile.

NOTE: Apparently I could force the system to compile using 2008's tooling, which may "cure" this.  But that means changing all of our projects up & down the chain to do this, which is rather backwards and contrary to the whole point of moving to 2010, no?

For the curious, the exact linker error:

```
odbccp32.lib(dllload.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___vsnprintf referenced in function _StringVPrintfWorkerA@20
```

Comment: Just an FYI - VS2012 Update 1 now allows you to target v110_xp tooling, which addresses the need to build for XP clients using the 2012 compiler, but they failed (again) to address the above issue.  So I am again forced to link against the Vista version of the ODBC libraries in order to produce an XP..Win8 compatible executable (statically linked).

Comment: The microsoft link seems to be broken. Omitting the URL parameter fixes it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470376/odbc-application-linking-with-odbccp32-lib-gets-link-errors-in-vs2010-beta-1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through your link, it seems that Microsoft has verified that there is a problem, and they intend to fix it in the *next* version of the SDK. Doesn't help much, does it?

It's quite normal for the linker to daisy-chain through the objects, linking one object only to discover that it has dependencies on other objects. If you want to preemptively link to a specific library, add it to the "Additional Dependencies" in the Linker Input tab of the project properties.

If you aren't able to get the linker to prefer a specific version of a library, just seek out and replace the version of the library in the installation.

I think this is a link to the Vista SDK, but I can't verify it: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ff6467e6-5bba-4bf5-b562-9199be864d29&displaylang=en

Comment: If you're doing the same, the trick is to place odbccp32.lib in a folder someplace, and add that path to your project's *Linker*'s Additional Library Directories (General sub-category) [not the compiler's settings.  And no direct reference to the lib need be made, just by including that path, with that file, will cause that to link ahead of the default paths for whatever version of VisualStudio and hence avoid the problem]

Answer (score 2):

I see it.  Ouch, my condolences.  Their advice is about as best as it is going to get if you don't want to compile with /MD.  I think I know the source of the problem, this isn't that easy to fix for them either.  It's going to require them getting the VS2010 CRT header file fixed first, then recompile and issue an SDK update.  That takes some major doing.

It is getting linked because it is listed in the "Core Windows Libraries" property sheet.  View + Property Manager to see it.  Not linking it is not an option, you are probably actually using it when you #include `<sql.h>`

The Vista version indeed doesn't have the same problem, it was probably built with an earlier version of VS.  Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies = "c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\lib\odbccp32.lib".  This injects the vista version before the 7.0 version.  You may have to live with this for a while, be sure to keep VS2008 installed on your build machines.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded explanation.  It is indeed very irritating that VS2010 has been out for quite a while, and yet this persists.  I guess the masses that are conditioned to use DLLs everywhere (despite the decades of DLL hell) are what constitute real-world-testing for MS Development team. :(

Comment: how do I look at the "Core Windows Libraries"?  View+Property Manager shows me a list of projects in my solution if a solution is loaded, and nothing if not.  Either case, nothing about "Core Windows Libraries"... nor do I see that under any project's properties...?

Comment: Hmya, be careful what you say, you're likely to run into the masses when you post to a Q+A site.  You might want to consider keeping your old tools around for a while if you insist on doing things the old but unscary way.  They just got scary.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the undefined `__imp___vsnprintf` symbol while converting an ODBC application to Visual Studio 2015. Figuring that there must be a workaround, I dumped all the symbols exported by the various libraries in the Visual Studio 2015 LIB directories with DUMPBIN and found that this library with a most obvious name, `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`, defines these symbols.

Adding this to the LINK command line resolved the missing external referenced by `odbccp32.lib`.

Once one knows what to search for, [some info is available here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5150eeec-4427-440f-ab19-aecb26113d31/updated-to-vs-2015-and-now-get-unresolved-external-errors?forum=vcgeneral).

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully this will help some folks.

Comment: You deserve a medal. Worked for me and saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know all the details, so shooting in the dark. When I had a situation when certain functions were available with one compiler and not the other, I created a simple DLL with the functions exported with C interface, using compiler version that supported those functions, and used that DLL with another compiler.

Comment: Interesting idea.  But this means creating a DLL to go with our app, which is one of the things I really wish to avoid.  Not a fan of DLL hell.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to link with just odbccp32.lib from v6.0 sdk all else from the default sdk.

**1. download v6.0 sdk** from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ff6467e6-5bba-4bf5-b562-9199be864d29&displaylang=en

(do not install documentation and samples/examples, the result is 75MB downlaod):

**2. create a folder, some folder.**

for example: lib_odbc_fromsdkv6.0 in your project's folder

**3. copy the file** odbccp32.lib **from:**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Lib
```

to folder created above (only one file).

**4. in each project's properties add that (lib_odbc_fromsdkv6.0) directory to Library directories:**

```
VC++ Directories -> Library directories
```

the depended projects in myodbc are **myodbc5S** and **myodbc-installer.**

(from Mordachai)