# odbcpp32.lib linking error after upgrading code to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++

After converting source code to Visual Studio 2010 from 2008 getting an error                 odbccp32.lib(dllload.obj) : error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _*imp*_vsnprintf referenced in function
Kindly provide the solution if anybody knows, I searched on various sites but didn't get any appropriate solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked the linker librarys? maybe they got discarded by covnersion?

Comment: In linker library there is a odbccp32.lib

Comment: its a standard lib, so you need no additional linker paths, do you?

Comment: no there is no any additional linker path, just the name of library

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: ODBC refuses to statically link to libcmt.lib under VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596212/c-odbc-refuses-to-statically-link-to-libcmt-lib-under-vs2010)

Comment: what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a KNOWN bug in odbccp.lib included with the PSDK 7.1. Simplest workaround, just add this code to one of your sources:

```
//---------------------------------------------------//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wtypes.h>

extern "C" int _imp___vsnprintf(
    char *buffer,
    size_t count,
    const char *format,
    va_list argptr
    )
{
    return vsnprintf( buffer, count, format, argptr );
}
//---------------------------------------------------//
```

It resolves the missing external, by creating a wrapper with the missing name and redirecting it to the correct statically linked symbol.

Worked for me. :-)